# Integer instructions can go past branches.what does this mean?

Tags: cpu-architecture

In Tomasulo's algorithm it is said that integer instructions can go past branches allowing floating point operations to go beyond basic blocks. What does this statement mean?

Comment: Can you post a link to the description that used this terminology? The description at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomasulo_algorithm for example describes the algorithm in very different words.

Comment: https://parasol.tamu.edu/~rwerger/Courses/614/lec/Lec16-dynamic1.ppt

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.csee.umbc.edu%2F~olano%2F611f12%2F08-tomasulo.pptx&ei=ktmDVNLCC5CiugTTiIL4Cg&usg=AFQjCNHdETAaLb1a_eLHBz2qlFNlD-ZZ3A&sig2=tVDOM8vx3sfGDp5NG0jchw&bvm=bv.80642063,d.c2E

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer architecture, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is referring to the concept in some processors the pipeline causes instructions  after a branch to execute. In a sequence like this:

```
   MOVL R10, R9
   BNEQ SOMEHWERE
   ADDL3 R1, R2, R3
```

The add instruction gets executed regardless of the outcome of the test and branch in the previous instruction. The compiler has to reorder the instructions (or place NOOPs after the branch).